# Conditional reminders in notion

Tags: notion-api, notion

I have a table using the [notion sales CRM template](https://www.notion.so/templates/sales-crm) which contains a last contact date column, I want to automatically send out a reminder if the last contact date is over 60 days from today.

Is there a way to do this within notion using notions builtin reminder features with if statements or do I need to use the notion API and just pull the data and do the checks myself everyday.